# Can Foreign Key on a table be three different tables as primary keys (each table primary key data is different)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a reminder table (ParentId) - Foreign key to ProductId from Product and also OrderId from Order table. Is it possible? When I try to insert the data for the Reminder table belongs to OrderId, I'm getting Foreign-Key constraint error.

```
Reminder
 - ReminderId
 - ParentId

Product
 - ProductId

Order
 - OrderId

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reminder]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Reminder_ProductId] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])

REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([ProductId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reminder] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Reminder_ProductId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reminder]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Reminder_OrderId] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Quote] ([QuoteId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reminder] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Reminder_OrderId]
GO
```

Comment: Which is the error you're getting?

Comment: Why do you have a FK called `FK_Reminder_OrderId` that links `ParentId`  to `[dbo].[Quote] ([QuoteId])` and has no connection to orders?

Comment: Why the NOCHECK?

Comment: Because you referenced the wrong table in your fkey (as @MartinSmith is subtly hinting at). And adding constraints with NOCHECK is dangerous because the underlying data could be invalid and SQL Server will potentially avoid using these keys because they are not trusted (due to the NOCHECK).

Comment: The mix-up between the Order and Quote tables is a red herring.  The real issue (I think) is that the OP wants a foreign key that allows values from two different primary keys.

Comment: What you're trying to do cannot be done when you have added the FK constraint. People have done it by skipping the constraint (I've seen a couple of threads here), but it sounds like a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: Sorry, Its not Quote, it should be Order table with OrderId.

Comment: If this is not possible, I can create two Remnder tables - ReminderProuduct and reminderOrder exclusively and reference to proper tables if the same table with parentId is a bad idea. The problem I'm getting is forign key constraint with Product table, when I try to add the data for OrderId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of work, using foreign key relationships and computed columns.  This does require a "type" of some sort in the table:

```
create table reminders (
    ReminderId . . . primary key,
    parentId int, -- presumably
    type varchar(255),
    check (type in ('product', 'order')),
    parent_productid as (case when type = 'product' then parentId end) persisted,
    parent_orderid as (case when type = 'order' then parentId end) persisted,
    foreign key (parent_productid) references products(productId),
    foreign key (parent_orderid) references orders(orderid)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d04b04b9ed77753ad1ee9e0568e430b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, I can try this. I appreciate it. The code for constraints work without error (I could add multiple foreign keys). But when I add the data, only Reminders table referencing Products table, but didn't like Orders table.

Comment: @dotNETEngineer . . . It works when I try it.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Awesome, I will try on my code this evening and get back to you. I've to recreate the table. If I can add below separately as a script and run the code without disturbing the table? I do have a type which states prod or ord as  you mentioned. Want to run as a script

check (type in ('product', 'order')),
    parent_productid as (case when type = 'product' then parentId end) persisted,
    parent_orderid  .....

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I recreated my table and used the foreign key relation as you suggested, it worked great, can't thank enough for your example through fiddle, made my life easy with a live example. Awesome, always happy to learn from techies like you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then No, this is not possible in any SQL database that I know of.

I believe you want to state that the value in ParentId must be present in *either* the Product table (ProductId field) or the Quote table (QuoteId field).  This is not allowed in Primary / Foreign Key relationships -- you can point the Foreign Key and one, and only one, Primary Key.

Comment: Thanks. So I can create different tables.